# Why is my pc dropping this UDP packet?

Tags: networking, ipv4, udp

I am using an FPGA to create IPv4/UDP packets.

Below is what the packet looks like. Wireshark doesn't flag it for errors at all. I'm using a UDP checksum of 0x0000 (allowed for IPv4), the MAC/IP destination matches, and the FCS and IPv4 checksum is correct.

I can only see the packets if I enable rx-all on the pc MAC using EthTool.

`sudo ethtool -K enp2s0 rx-all on`

If this is off (the usual mode of operation), these packets get dropped by the PC before reaching wireshark, and they're marked as frame errors.

`sudo ethtool -S enp2s0` doesn't show anything helpful.

And I have double checked the dest MAC/IP with my pc.

If I take out the IPv4 portion of the header (so just a raw Ethernet packet), the packets are let through even with `rx-all off`. (I can include that too below but it's already a lot to include as-is). Since the raw packet works, I'm fairly certain I have the MII interface and Ethernet framing correct.

I've been over everything I can't figure out why these packets are still being dropped. My goal is to create UDP packets that can be transmitted over a normal network (through switches, etc).

Is there anything else I've missed? Do I need to serve up ARP packets as well? Do I need the UDP checksum anyway?

```
$ sudo ifconfig enp2s0
enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.100  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        ether 74:d4:35:aa:9d:1a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 26372  bytes 13819100 (13.1 MiB)
        RX errors 177  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 177
        TX packets 1613  bytes 137389 (134.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

```
$ sudo ethtool -S enp2s0
NIC statistics:
     tx_packets: 1597
     rx_packets: 26372
     tx_errors: 0
     rx_errors: 0
     rx_missed: 0
     align_errors: 0
     tx_single_collisions: 0
     tx_multi_collisions: 0
     unicast: 26372
     broadcast: 0
     multicast: 0
     tx_aborted: 0
     tx_underrun: 0
```

```
Frame 1257: 54 bytes on wire (432 bits), 54 bytes captured (432 bits) on interface enp2s0, id 0
    Section number: 1
    Interface id: 0 (enp2s0)
    Encapsulation type: Ethernet (1)
    Arrival Time: Nov 24, 2023 15:24:18.467278031 SAST
    [Time shift for this packet: 0.000000000 seconds]
    Epoch Time: 1700832258.467278031 seconds
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.127289169 seconds]
    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.127289169 seconds]
    [Time since reference or first frame: 4627.139850121 seconds]
    Frame Number: 1257
    Frame Length: 54 bytes (432 bits)
    Capture Length: 54 bytes (432 bits)
    [Frame is marked: False]
    [Frame is ignored: False]
    [Protocols in frame: eth:ethertype:ip:udp:data]
    [Coloring Rule Name: UDP]
    [Coloring Rule String: udp]
Ethernet II, Src: PcsCompu_fb:dd:66 (08:00:27:fb:dd:66), Dst: Giga-Byt_aa:9d:1a (74:d4:35:aa:9d:1a)
    Destination: Giga-Byt_aa:9d:1a (74:d4:35:aa:9d:1a)
    Source: PcsCompu_fb:dd:66 (08:00:27:fb:dd:66)
    Type: IPv4 (0x0800)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.1.101, Dst: 192.168.1.100
    0100 .... = Version: 4
    .... 0101 = Header Length: 20 bytes (5)
    Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP: CS0, ECN: Not-ECT)
        0000 00.. = Differentiated Services Codepoint: Default (0)
        .... ..00 = Explicit Congestion Notification: Not ECN-Capable Transport (0)
    Total Length: 40
    Identification: 0x0000 (0)
    000. .... = Flags: 0x0
    ...0 0000 0000 0000 = Fragment Offset: 0
    Time to Live: 64
    Protocol: UDP (17)
    Header Checksum: 0xf6ab [correct]
    [Header checksum status: Good]
    [Calculated Checksum: 0xf6ab]
    Source Address: 192.168.1.101
    Destination Address: 192.168.1.100
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 65535, Dst Port: 65535
    Source Port: 65535
    Destination Port: 65535
    Length: 20
    Checksum: 0x0000 [zero-value ignored]
        [Checksum Status: Not present]
    [Stream index: 43]
    [Timestamps]
        [Time since first frame: 43.780741653 seconds]
        [Time since previous frame: 40.026103244 seconds]
    UDP payload (12 bytes)
Data (12 bytes)
    Data: 53574954434845533a2087e0
    [Length: 12]
```

Previously asked on [network engineering stackexchange](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/84528/why-is-my-pc-dropping-this-udp-packet).

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, finally!!

Turns out the packet was too short. The minimum ethernet packet length is 64B, this packet was 54B.